# Why is my MarkupString not rendering correctly?

Tags: css, razor, markup

I have a conditional line of Razor code:

```
<BSCol MD="3" Class="d-flex justify-content-center"><b>@(_bid.PriceGuarantee ? "Price Is Guaranteed" : ((MarkupString)"<div class='text-danger'>Price Is NOT Guaranteed</div>"))</b></BSCol>
```

And it is rendering:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Html.Raw(MarkupString)`. Should be used with `caution`, as it exposes you to `cross site scripting vulnerabilities`.

Comment: @KarenPayne I actually was able to work around this issue, by putting in some if (...) else (...) conditions